# hide() the rows that have any "td:empty" and keep the first column's matching index.value in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have a HTML table with checkbox options for the user above the table.**
**As the user checks boxes, those columns appear on the table**

## HTML

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4">
 <div class="icon-box">
  <h3>Color of Fish</h3>
  <li class="listPrint"><input type="checkbox" value="hide" id="red" onchange="hide_show_table(this.id);"> Red</li>
  <li class="listPrint"><input type="checkbox" value="hide" id="blue" onchange="hide_show_table(this.id);"> Blue</li>
  <li class="listPrint"><input type="checkbox" value="hide" id="yellow" onchange="hide_show_table(this.id);"> Yellow</li>
 </div>
</div>

<table id="table2" class="mx-auto mb-5" width="100%">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Fish</th>
     <th id="red_head">Red</th>
     <th id="blue_head">Blue</th>
     <th id="yellow_head">Yellow</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
      
 <tbody>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td class="fish"><a href="#"><div>Bluefin</div></a></td>
      <td class="red"></td>
      <td class="blue"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></td>
      <td class="yellow"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td class="fish"><a href="#"><div>Redtail</div></a></td>
      <td class="red"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></td>
      <td class="blue"></td>
      <td class="yellow"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td class="fish"><a href="#"><div>Rainbow</div></a></td>
      <td class="red"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></td>
      <td class="blue"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></td>
      <td class="yellow"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></td>
    </tr>
 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

## JS

```
/////////////check boxes//////////////
function hide_show_table(col_name)
{
 var checkbox_val=document.getElementById(col_name).value;
 if(checkbox_val=="show")
 {
  var all_col=document.getElementsByClassName(col_name);
  for(var i=0;i<all_col.length;i++)
  {
   all_col[i].style.display="none";
  }
  document.getElementById(col_name+"_head").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById(col_name).value="hide";
 }
 else
 {
  var all_col=document.getElementsByClassName(col_name);

  for(var i=0;i<all_col.length;i++)
  {
   all_col[i].style.display="table-cell";
  }
  document.getElementById(col_name+"_head").style.display="table-cell";
  document.getElementById(col_name).value="show";
 }
}
```

## CSS

```
#red_head {
  display: none;
}
.red {
  display: none;
}

#blue_head {
  display: none;
}
.blue {
  display: none;
}

#yellow_head {
  display: none;
}
.yellow {
  display: none;
}
```

**I would like to hide() the rows that have any "td:empty"**
**Such as: on open, the fish column and data are shown. As the user checks colors, those columns show. At the same time, if the fish do not have that color... those rows are hidden.**

**I've tried javascripts loops... now I have been trying Jquery. I seem to be closer to getting it in Jquery with:**

```
if($('tr:has("td:empty")')) {
  if("td:empty") {
    $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    } else {
      $(this).closest("tr").show();
    }
  }
```

**If I hide the fish column on open, it kinda does what I want. It hides rows with all null cells. However, I am trying to hide rows with any null cells and keep the fish that matches**
**I, also, tried**

```
$('tr:has("td:empty")).hide();
```

**However, no values show..."

Answer (score 1):

Well... here's one way to do it but frankly it is quite messy. I just iterate the rows then the cells, filtering by a cell that is empty and also its related checkbox is checked. If a rows has such a cell then hide the row.

```js
/////////////check boxes//////////////
function hide_show_table(col_name) {
  var checkbox_val = document.getElementById(col_name).value;
  if (checkbox_val == "show") {
    var all_col = document.getElementsByClassName(col_name);
    for (var i = 0; i < all_col.length; i++) {
      all_col[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(col_name + "_head").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(col_name).value = "hide";
  } else {
    var all_col = document.getElementsByClassName(col_name);

    for (var i = 0; i < all_col.length; i++) {
      all_col[i].style.display = "table-cell";
    }
    document.getElementById(col_name + "_head").style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById(col_name).value = "show";
  }

  hide_show_rows();
}

function hide_show_rows() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".listPrint [type=checkbox]");
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#table2 tbody tr");
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    var cells = [...row.querySelectorAll("td:not(:first-child)")]
    var empty = cells.filter(function(cell, index) {
      return !cell.innerHTML && checkboxes[index].checked
    })
    if (empty.length) {
      row.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    } else {
      row.style.visibility = 'visible'
    }
  })

}
```

```css
#red_head {
  display: none;
}

.red {
  display: none;
}

#blue_head {
  display: none;
}

.blue {
  display: none;
}

#yellow_head {
  display: none;
}

.yellow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4">
  <div class="icon-box">
    <h3>Color of Fish</h3>
    <li class="listPrint"><label><input type="checkbox" value="hide" id="red" onchange="hide_show_table(this.id);"> Red</label></li>
    <li class="listPrint"><label><input type="checkbox" value="hide" id="blue" onchange="hide_show_table(this.id);"> Blue</label></li>
    <li class="listPrint"><label><input type="checkbox" value="hide" id="yellow" onchange="hide_show_table(this.id);"> Yellow</label></li>
  </div>
</div>

<table id="table2" class="mx-auto mb-5" border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fish</th>
      <th id="red_head">Red</th>
      <th id="blue_head">Blue</th>
      <th id="yellow_head">Yellow</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td class="fish">
        <a href="#">
          <div>Bluefin</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="red"></td>
      <td class="blue"><i class="fa-solid fa-check" /></td>
      <td class="yellow"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td class="fish">
        <a href="#">
          <div>Redtail</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="red"><i class="fa-solid fa-check" /></td>
      <td class="blue"></td>
      <td class="yellow"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td class="fish">
        <a href="#">
          <div>Rainbow</div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="red"><i class="fa-solid fa-check" /></td>
      <td class="blue"><i class="fa-solid fa-check" /></td>
      <td class="yellow"><i class="fa-solid fa-check" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: well... that definitely does what I was asking. Thank you for taking the time. Can you push me in a direction I might go to have the row(s) that are hidden collapse. Let's say: I have a list of 100 fish and only 3 meet the checked criteria. How would I get the table to collapse and show those 3 on the top rows of the table so the user would not have to scroll?

Comment: oh, you mean just to hide them using `display:none` rather than `visibility:hidden`? or something fancier?

Comment: I really should have played with it before asking. display:none That was it. THANK YOU!!! It always amazes me how I can spend days on something and you guys spend seconds. I'll get there. Thanks again.

Comment: How would I add a "uncheck" function to this? So, when the user unchecks an option they had checked, the table will show the value that was filtered from being checked. I've been playing with .prop("checked", false); but unsuccessful.

Comment: didn't understand. when i uncheck an option the table reverts to state before the check. how is that different?

Comment: That is what I am looking to do. For some reason it is not on my end. The rows that go hidden on check, remain hidden when unchecked.

Comment: Your code is perfect. I was playing with it and deleted a character causing it to error. THANKs for your response.